# Iframe trim size

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-canvas

I have an HTML Facebook app that's been using fixed canvas so far. Now I want to use the fluid width, but also to leave an option to go back to using fixed width. The problem is that I had to increase width of my app and when I switch back to fixed width, it cuts the right part of my app to reach 760px. What I want is for the app to be trimmed on both sides equally. Is there a way to achieve this?